# AngularJS - Change scope with one of the iterations of a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a project with Angular where I don't want to use a select element with ng-options, so I made up a list with different options in order to select one of them.

```
<div class="countrylist">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in shippingCountry"><p>{{c.name}}</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So the option selected would modify another element where the chosen option would be displayed.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>{{selectedCountry}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In order to do that, I would need to pass the data from the chosen option of the first element into the 2nd one. I have tried doing something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="c in shippingCountry" ng-click="selectedCountry = {{c}}"><p>{{c.name}}</p></li>
```

with no success.

You can check the [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hBlTdq0VTgi9bUJ1VqWG?p=preview) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a function over there like this in the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YN0gQehMB4o7qxg5u3DK?p=preview)

```
<li ng-repeat="c in shippingCountry" ng-click="Click(c)"><p>{{c.name}}</p></li>
```

Having this method in your controller

```
$scope.Click=function (c)  
 {
   $scope.select=c;

 }
```

Comment: I mark this as correct as it seems the more appropiate way to do it in Angular, and it was posted before the one Antonio posted. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: do you think it is more correct that one? (I know working with $parent could be a little bit tricky, but if you feel that it is a better way to do it, I will mark Sajeendran one

Answer (score 1):

It creates child scope for each iteration, so explicitly refer parent scope:

Change like this,

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="c in shippingCountry" ng-click="$parent.selectedCountry = c"><p>{{c.name}}</p></li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/BFuMHnppongT7XTDJcyZ?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed your [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oi3pcoH3YcB82xkHTktJ?p=preview). It would be better to use methods in scope for this operations because they work in current scope, not in child

```
<li ng-repeat="c in shippingCountry" ng-click="selectCountry(c)">
    <p>{{c.name}}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// .html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>{{selectedCountry.item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="countrylist">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in shippingCountry" ng-click="selectedCountry.item = c"><p>{{c.name}}</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>

// controller
$scope.selectedCountry = {
  item: $scope.shippingCountry[0]
};
```

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/07j21jjApT32ltG349zE?p=preview)